# И где зал славы? (leagues)

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

На странице справки [Почему так важно принимать участие в оценке вопросов и ответов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) присутствует такой текст:

> Поэтому в [зале славы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/leagues) публикуют списки пользователей с максимальным рейтингом за неделю, месяц, сезон, год или за все время.

но ссылка `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/leagues` под словами `зале славы` ведёт на несуществующую страницу.

---

#### Дополнение

На `stackoverflow.com` внутри [аналогичной страницы](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) приведена другая ссылка: http://stackexchange.com/leagues, где приведены ссылки для сайтов сети se. В частности, для нашего сайта: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/355/week/ru-stackoverflow

Может быть, её и надо привести в справочной странице? или, хотя бы `http://stackexchange.com/leagues`

Comment: Вероятно, [вот он](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users).

Comment: Вы просто недостойны войти в священный зал :)

Comment: @D-side а вроде бы тут https://stackexchange.com/leagues/

Comment: @Nikita да, это больше похоже.

Comment: Кажется кто-то захватил ruSO https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcCeO.jpg

Comment: @АлексейШиманский плодятся как кролики

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Большое спасибо за отзыв! Поправил страницу справки на русском языке, теперь ссылка должна быть как и на англоязычной странице.